# several .dat files - can these be safely deleted

Tags: dropbox

In my Dropbox folder in computer as also on the cloud I see many files for example 
SyncToy_2c213230-95b1-41b5-a2b1-87722834edce.dat.
Can these be safely deleted since these are pretty old files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no definitive answer.  Try moving the files out of Dropbox and seeing if you have any problems over the next couple of weeks.  Depending on your Dropbox settings, you may also be able to delete the files then recover them later from Dropbox.

I suspect they are not Dropbox files but don't know offhand specific programs that use similar filenames.  Try searching Google for the filename and see if you can find a program-maybe it's one you used to have but have uninstalled.  Good luck!